# How to zip long string into file and retrieve it?

Tags: java, string, file, zip

I am trying to zip a long string into a file and to retrieve it.

The following code does not work. What it retrieves is gibberish.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    try {

        // Creating base for data
        StringBuilder sbb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i=0;i<1000;i++)
            sbb.append("ùertyty!|").append(Integer.toString(i));

        File FileAll = new File(".\\All.data");
        FileAll.createNewFile();

        // Zipping into file
        DeflaterOutputStream g = new DeflaterOutputStream(
                new FileOutputStream(FileAll));

        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(g);

        String base = sbb.toString();
        osw.write(base);
        osw.close();

        FileInputStream ALL_FIS = new FileInputStream(FileAll);

        // Re-reading from file
        DeflaterInputStream dis = new DeflaterInputStream(ALL_FIS);
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(dis);

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        char[] c = new char[1000];

        int count = isr.read(c);

        while ( count != -1 ) {
            sb.append(c, 0, count);
            count = isr.read(c);
        }

        isr.close();

        String retr = sb.toString();
        System.out.println("Are equal: " + retr.equals(base));
        System.out.println("Base: " + base);
        System.out.println("Retr: " + retr);

    } catch (IOException e) {

        System.err.println(e.toString());

    }

}
```

What am I doing wrong?

P.S.: It seems like DeflaterInputStream does not do its job and returns the content of the file as is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use a InflaterInputStream (which decompresses) instead of a DeflaterInputStream

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/zip/InflaterInputStream.html